# ng-show based on dynamic conditions from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

We are working on some dynamic form where user can create questions in the admin panel and put conditions to show them  based on other questions values.

```
ng-show="((UserCode==10003 && Name=='Ankur') ||(StateId=='NY'))"
```

this works fine show/hide question based on other questions value, But the conditions are dynamic and created runtime based on the users selected values in database.. how can we add ng-show conditions dynamic ?

I tried this

```
$scope.Condition = "((UserCode==10003 && Name=='Ankur') ||(StateId=='NY'))";
```

and `ng-show="{{Condition}}"` but this didn't worked.

UserId, Name & StateId are other questions on the page.

Please let me know if i missed some info.

thanks

Comment: Is this inside an ng-for or someting? Can you add those code as well explaining where `UserCode`, `Name` and `StateId` is coming from?

Comment: updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with method:

```
ng-show="condition()"
$scope.condition =  function() {
    /* You calculate your condition here */
    var condition = ... ;
    return condition;
}
```

Comment: Conditions are dynamic and based on database values, there are 30 questions each having their own conditions..

Answer (score 0):

You know this is a string and not a condition that will return true or false.. ?

```
$scope.Condition = "((UserCode==10003 && Name=='Ankur') ||(StateId=='NY'))";
```

This should be correct

```
$scope.Condition = (UserCode==10003 && Name=='Ankur') ||(StateId=='NY');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.Condition = "((UserCode==10003 && Name=='Ankur') ||(StateId=='NY'))";
```

this will never work because it is not a function or condition that returns a true or false,

try with thist

```
$scope.condition = function(_usercode, _name, _state_id){
return (UserCode == _usercode && Name == _name) || (StateId == _state_id);
}
```

and in html `ng-show="condition(10003,'Ankur','NY')"`